# Cluster communication - SQL Server Failover Cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustering

I am running a lab enviornment on my laptop two node SQL 2008 R2  running on 
windows 2008 R2 clustered Vms

Based on my understanding

a) Public Network or all Communication network

I see checkbox is enabled for cluster communication on this network also.

b) Private or HeartBeat or Cluster communication only network.

It appears to me that currently public network is used for cluster communication?

Is this correct? Does heartbeat network is used only for redundancy and cluster communication is primarily done on public network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the version of SQL but the version of Windows you're working with. Win 2008 changed things up quite a bit, [private heartbeat network is no longer required.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197454%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[Pre Win 2008 cluster reqs.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258750)

Comment: I disagree, you do need private network for redundancy see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverClustering/thread/017ad86f-7166-4628-bf1d-148cdf8e9d06 My question is why it uses public network for heartbeat though it should use private?

Comment: See the bottom of your link for a post about virtual adapter usage. If I read the above correctly, you are doing this on a couple laptops, so I'd suggest reading up on virtual adapters.